# Hash::check Always Failing

Tags: laravel-4

I've done projects with Auth on Linux and Windows and never ran across hashing issues. The basic gist of it is the passwords do not pass the Hash::check method with the default User setup. I've looked at most of the answers on SO and they are the typical users not understanding Hash makes a different value each time, or that Hash::check requires the plain value then the hashed value from the user in the db. At first this was a failure of Auth::attempt, but looking further seems to be a hash verification issue. I've already read and re-read [Laravel Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/security) to make sure I didn't miss something like ensuring the db password field was too short (set to length of 256 just to be sure).

**Setup**

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
  protected $fillable = array(
    'email',
    'password',
  );

  protected $guarded = array(
  'id',
  );

  //add the UserInterface / RemindableInterface methods here
}
```

**Seed**

```
User::create(array( //could also do DB insert way..
  'id'=>1,
  'email' => 'admin@example.com',
  'password' => Hash::make('admin'),
));

//User created with correct hash no problem.
```

**Test Post Route**

```
//some other validation above this. Email / password correctly passed from form
$email = Input::get('email');
$password = Input::get('password');

$user = User::where('email', $email)->first();
//gets user with hashed pass fine
$sucess = Hash::check( $password, $user->password ); //could do $user->getAuthPassword() as well
//always false..
//initially tried Auth::attempt getting the same results because of the internal Hash::check
```

**Tried**

- I've stepped through the validation down to the comparison of the db hash with salt against the inserted plain pass, which failed after salt comparison.
- I've tried creating a fresh user on the get sign in route (below) and trying those credentials on the form and it still wouldn't sign in (Figured it might have been a seed issue.)

  $newUser = new User(array(
    'email'=>'admin2@example.com',
    'password'=>Hash::make('test')
  ));
  $newUser->save();

At this point it would seem to be a odd password_verify / password_hash issue under the hood I'm unaware of.

Comment: What happens if you `Hash::check('admin', Hash::make('admin'))`?

Comment: Works great (returns true). One of those situations I was expecting to fail after all this, but still leaves me mind boggled.

Comment: Then likely `Input::get('password')` isn't what you think it is or `$user->password` isn't. Do you have a unique index on email? No duplicate emails with different passwords? Do you have a `creating` listener in the model that's hashing the password a second time?

Comment: Turns out there was a mutator I had to dig a little deeper for. Thank you for the quick review though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out a default setPasswordAttribute method was set on the user model, which runs for any created or constructed user via the start fillers.

Remove:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute( $value )
{
  $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make( $value );
}
```

And presto it works fine.